# what's the point of using event callback in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

i was wondering if we call a function directly, why should we use event call back ?
for example i use event callback to set color of a component from child to parent

this is child component

```
<button @onclick="OnButtonClick">Click me</button>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnColorChange { get; set; }

    private async Task OnButtonClick()
    {
        await OnColorChange.InvokeAsync("new-color");
    }
}
```

and this is parent component

```
<ChildComponent OnColorChange="HandleColorChange" />



@code {
    private string currentColorClass = "default-color";


    private void HandleColorChange(string newColorClass)
    {
        currentColorClass = newColorClass;

    }
}
```

so insted of all of these define HandleColorChange as public static and we can just call it directly like this

```
ParentComponent.HandleColorChange("new-color");
```

and this isn't only problem , we use js interop to call c# function , although we can handle all of these by calling it directly, and the final question is : when we can handle by this way and when we shouldn't

Comment: which 'ParentComponent' would that be, as your component can be used in multiple places? How does your child component know that the current "parent" has a HandleColorChange method?

Comment: You answered yourself - EventCallback is used when you want to "call" parent component. Your solution with static method will not work, because in that case you cannot use `currentColorClass` which belongs to the instance. If you also make `currentColorClass` static it will keep its value for all of the component instances.  

I have to admit I am bit lost what you are actually asking about. Can you rephrase the last 2 paragraphs?

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing yes the child component can use in multiple places and because the function inside parent component is public static when we Call Parent Component and press dot the intellisense show me the methods

Comment: Your component can exist zero or more times at any given moment. Your component does not - or at least should not - depend on a particular type of parent component. Dependencies should be injected via the constructor and parameters. Changes in state should be communicated out by event callbacks. These are all hallmarks of good design - dependency injection, loose coupling. Why would you want to undo that by making a component an effective singleton that is tightly coupled to a parent?

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question?  It may be a little left field, but it's a valid question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad because:

1. Components are meant to be reusable.
2. You are tightly coupling the child to the parent.
3. You can only have zero or one instances [which you can't guarantee].  Image a column component in a table: you would update all the columns.
4. The various other reasons given by knowledgeable programmers in the comments.

So:

> when we can handle by this way and when we shouldn't

Never do it this way, which should be apparent from the comments.

You're creating a single use component for a very specific use case.  You might as well forget the component and just create a render fragment you can use in the parent component.  That way you forgo all the expense of a component.

In the end it's your code, so your decision.

An important point to understand is you don't control the creation, lifecycle or disposal of components.  That's the responsibility of the Renderer.